# PHP-Facebook post as page without page token

Tags: php, facebook, api, laravel

I use Laravel socialite package and I take

```
permission('manage_pages',
'publish_pages',
'publish_actions',
'ads_management',
'business_management', 'ads_read'),
```

After than get access token in callback.

When I try post as page with access token but post seems like visitor post.

What am I supposed to do? Here is my code:

```
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'appid',
    'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7',
]);

$params=[
    'message'=>'Example Post',
    'access_token'=>'ACCESS_TOKEN',

];

try{
    $ret=$fb->post('/PAGEID/feed',$params);
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$graphNode = $ret->getGraphNode();

print_r($graphNode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a **Page Token** with the `publish_pages` permission. If it gets posted as visitor, you are using a **User Token**.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I think these links are a little bit outdated but thanks for help

Comment: the second one is older, but the information is definitely not outdated. only the php sdk code may be a bit outdated. the first one is from the facebook docs.

Comment: after all it´s just a simple API call to get a page token: /PAGE-ID?fields=access_token

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer :)